Stop screw stripped on rear derailleur
I've got a suntour seven rear derailleur that I'm trying to overhaul, but I let Mechanical Rage get the best of me and now the stop screw is totally stripped.
How do I get it off, and is there any cost-effective way to replace it?
Relatedly, the top jockey wheel bolt is stuck (and probably stripped) so I'd be happy to hear advice about that as well.
Edit: it's the screw head that I stripped. Here are pictures of the stop screw:


Edit 2: I believe what I'm asking about is also called a "cage stop pin".

Is it the head of the screw or the threads that are stripped?

Have you tried WD40 or something similar?  You may still be able to remove the stop screw with a pair of long-nose pliers...

You are mentioning the limit  screw but the photo shows the barrel adjuster??

Excuse me, I meant to say "stop screw". Edited comment: I have not tried WD-40 and pliers. One concern is being able to tighten the stop screw again after (so that the derailleur remains functional). Is there somewhere I can get a replacement screw?

Unless you have a particular need to retain the old deraileur (period correct vintage etc) A new derailleur is the best functional fix. Local bike coop or recycle center is an option for a very low cost fix.

@LucasMyers, I am guessing here but it looks to me that the stop screw is only functional when the chain is not running through the derailleur, unless the chain is too long or it's under maintenance.
I would not remove it at all and keep working on the rest of the derailleur.

@MindDBike I'm trying to give it a deep clean and re-lube/grease the pivot/spring mechanism because it's kind of sticky and not shifting super well (also coated with dirt). I need to de-tension the spring to take it out, and that's only possible by taking out the stop screw.

@mattnz that's probably the right thing, it's just bugging me that it's an otherwise perfectly good derailleur which is impossible to do maintainance on.

I've watch twice the suntour seven video link from your question.
I think you have two options.
The first option is dipping the whole derailleur into turpentine, use a small bucket where the derailleur just fits fine so as to use the least amount of mineral turpentine and leave it in for a few hours or overnight.
Then try moving the derailleur to see it's spring action is looser and stronger and working as expected.  If at this stage you think all is good with it's function and it just needs a cleanup, get an old tooth brush and clean as much grime off it and then let it drip dry.  Once dry lubricate all parts with oil.
The second option and the hardest, is to continue with dismantling the derailleur with the Stopper screw still in place.  Watch the video at least two or three times to make sure you understand how to proceed.
Be careful, clinical and methodical, you will have to remove the spring under tension and instead of pushing the spring anchor/barrel from the bottom you will have to pull it out from the top, I suggest pliers.
If you persist this way you would get to the point where both jokey wheels would be off the cage and at this stage you can hold on to the bottom cage plate, where the Stopper is screwed into, and turn it clockwise to loosen it as if you would loosen a nut from a bolt facing the bold head, or the other way, anticlockwise as if loosening a nut from a bolt facing the nut.  Once the Stopper screw is loose then you can proceed to cleaning and assembling it.  During assembly, I think with the aid of thread-lock, you can still put enough torque on the stopper screw with a Phillip head screw driver to lock it in place.
I suggest to try both options starting with option one first so if you have to move into option two, all parts will be looser and easier to work with.

The photo shows the barrel adjuster not the limit screw. If in fact this barrel adjuster is the problem part, you can work around it. I have had adjusters so seized the threads failed. You can get a generic in line barrel adjuster. It can be installed anywhere in the shifter cable housing. You could mount it close to the shifter so you can fine tune shifting while riding.

Excuse me, I mistakenly wrote "limit screw" in my comment. In the question (and now in the revised comment), I meant "stop screw", which keeps the derailleur from completely rotating to take the tension out of the spring. The barrel adjuster is just dandy.
